# Android: Nearby api, No Connection

Tags: android, google-nearby

I am attempting to get [Google Nearby API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/get-started#before_you_begin) working on my handset (an s5).

I am building and running the stock project from github [Google Nearby API GIT](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/connections-quickstart).

The app builds and runs, with no errors. Having exported the app onto two S5s (amongst other handsets I have attempted to test it with) and connecting to a WLAN from a D-Link DSL-3680. Multicasting is enabled and set to v3.

However the app refuses to connect with the neighbouring phone when corresponding 'advertise' and 'discover' instructions have been given.

Is there an effective way in which to debug this behaviour? If I can provide an effective information dump of information that might help someone identify the issue then please let me know how.

Comment: Does the "Nearby in Use" notification show? Make sure both phones are connected to the internet, and that you are using an API key with the Nearby Messages API enabled. Take a look at the logs generated by the phone and see if anything stands out.

Comment: fwiw, this is the Nearby Connections API, so I wouldn't expect the "Nearby in Use" notification to show up (it only shows up for Nearby Messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'refuse to connect'? 
are you getting connection status- 'Rejected'?

If you are able to advertise and discover other devices, I'm assuming all your base conditions (like connected to local network) are fulfilled

Now,

You can try logging your status in Connection call back when you try to connect

```
Nearby.Connections.sendConnectionRequest(mGoogleApiClient, myName,
remoteEndpointId, myPayload, new Connections.ConnectionResponseCallback() {//response conditions}
```

using--
inside connection callback function write

```
          if(status.isSuccess()){
           // Successful connection
        } else {
          // Failed connection
        }
```

similarly, if you are not doing this, you need to  accept the connection request

```
Nearby.Connections.acceptConnectionRequest(mGoogleApiClient, remoteEndpointId, myPayload, this)
```

and inside Onresult callback add-

```
      if(status.isSuccess()){
       // Successful connection
    } else {
      // Failed connection
    }
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Hi, I am accepting this answer because although the team ran out of time and opted to do things the 'old fashioned way' using ip's, the effort given here will, I hope, assist the next person who ends up here from google/the search function. -- I know this is late - I ran away from everything software following the end of the exam period!! So apologies for that - better than never I guess....

Comment: well... the whole idea of stack exchange is to have a platform where people can help each other :)
thanks for such a humble response anyway :D